# Why don't CAS users show up in users_field_data?

Tags: users

I have a simple multisite setup in Drupal 8. I installed the [CAS module](https://www.drupal.org/project/cas) and verified that at least one user logged in successfully using our university's CAS server.

I can see the user at /admin/people, but I cannot see his entry in the database. I looked in the tables users, users_data, and users_field_data, and all I can see is the admin user (me).

Where are the users located in the database?

I need to know for a custom module I am developing. FWIW I do have "Auto Register Users" enabled in the module configuration.

Comment: Haven't figured it out yet, but you can use `User::load($user_id)` to load a user entity, and it works with CAS users just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For D8, CAS requires External Authentication module.

- External Authentication maintains a db table called [authmap](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/externalauth/tree/externalauth.install#n14).
- CAS maintains a table named [cas_login_data](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/cas/tree/cas.install#n16).

I suspect the data you're looking for is in one of those tables.

Comment: Looks like it's in authmap! How does User::load($uid) know to load from authmap though?

Comment: I looked at both modules twice, and couldn't figure it out for the life of me. CAS is definitely leveraging externalauth events to access and alter the data as a user is registered, but I couldn't find the start of the chain. Couldn't find how externalauth hooked into core mechanisms.  Sorry ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯